# How to block pulling from the master branch in a git repo

Tags: git

I wish to allow a contractor to pull and push to a branch, but to have no access to the master branch - is this possible?  (I'm running my own git server, not through github.)

(For more context - I need to protect some files.  I could use the submodule approach, but the files need to be there for the project to run - I need them to be redacted versions.)

Comment: What is your "git server"? Is access over ssh? Or are you using an on-premise or open-source version of something like GitLab? Or something else?

Comment: Ubuntu running git server, users connecting over ssh.

Comment: For `git` over `ssh` [tag:gitolite] provides branch protection. https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to hide refs with some tools or using namespaces, but it's not effective: a user can still steal the objects from the remote repository anyway.  From `gitnamespaces(7)`:

> The fetch and push protocols are not designed to prevent one side from stealing data from the other repository that was not intended to be shared. If you have private data that you need to protect from a malicious peer, your best option is to store it in another repository. This applies to both clients and servers. In particular, namespaces on a server are not effective for read access control; you should only grant read access to a namespace to clients that you would trust with read access to the entire repository.

If you need to restrict access to those files, you need to use a separate repository that contains only the branches you want the user to have access to.